# hashcode() vs toString().hashcode();

Tags: java, hashcode

Just trying to discuss and understand the difference between the below codes.

a >

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.addAll(str);
int hashcode= set.toString().hashCode();
```

b>

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.addAll(str);
int hashcode = set.hashCode();
```

I have checked if you are putting the same string element in both set in any order, hashcode return value will be the same. Just wanted to know is condition a>  more secure than

Comment: The difference is that ur asking for a `hashCode` on the set directly vs on a string representation of it. If you happen to get the same values than this is pure coincidence and can and will change with any Java update.

The string representation of the set might change. The hashCode implementation of String might change. The hashCode implementation of TreeSet might change. And if any of those changes, then the hash will definitely be different between the two.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure" in this situation? Secure against what?

Comment: hashcodes here are not cryptographic hashes. but yeah you can't talk about security without an idea of what the threat is.

Comment: @Zabuzza `String` and `Set` is defined. (Although in 1.00 `String` did have an impossible definition, it should remain the same from 1.1.)

Comment: If a cryptographic hash were substituted (and that is the angle that is being worried about), then the `toString` method does not produce secure hashes as the separator may appear within the element strings. Stringifying keys is a too common cause of vulnerabilities.

Comment: i tried it set.hashcode(); and set.toString.hascode() produces different result

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan They produce different results from one another (obviously), but they should be consistent themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The first snippet converts the set to a string (a potentially heavy operation), and then hashes it. The second hashs the set directly.

Since equal sets would produce equal strings and equal hashs, both methods are technically OK, but it's really redundant to convert the set to a string first (method a) - there's no benefit in using it, and all you're doing is wasting resources on the conversion to string.

Comment: "equal sets would produce equal strings" Is that guaranteed? Since sets don't guarantee order, couldn't the set `[1,2,3]` sometimes produce the string `[1,3,2]` and sometimes `[3,2,1]`?

Comment: @Sweeper `TreeSet`s guarantee order. The only issue is if `compareTo` and `equals` disagrees (`BigInteger` and, apparently, `Double`).

Comment: @Sweeper yes - the order of a set isn't guaranteed, but it's stable. Given the same JRE and JDK, the same set will always have the same order. Moreover, as Tom mentioned, these are SortedSets, so the order is guaranteed anyway